# A loop that grabs the value of certain items and then adds all values found

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I need some help in creating a loop for my following issue.

I have a list of items in column K, and their values are in column L.

What I want to do is:

For every cell in column K that contains "Item1" grab it's value and add all the values found.

I'm trying to accomplish this without having to paste every value found in column N and then add them up.

Below is my code.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("K1:K10")

    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Activate
        Val1 = cell.Value
        If Val1 = "Item1" Then
            Val2 = ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1") = "" Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1") = Val2
            Else
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N33").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Val2
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next cell

    Range("N11").Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-10]C:R[-1]C)"

End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I misunderstood the question. The following is the modified code to calculate the sum purely in VBA without writing the individual values out to the worksheet:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim Val1 As Variant
    Dim Sum As Double: Sum = 0

    Set rng = Range("K1:K10")

    For Each cell In rng
        Val1 = cell.Value
        If Val1 = "Item1" Then
            Sum = Sum + cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value
        End If
    Next cell

    Range("N11").Value2 = Sum

End Sub
```

---

From the Original Answer:

One really important Golden Rule you need to learn about programming in VBA is **Never use Activate and ActiveCell**.

I've refactored your code to show how to do so (plus demonstrate a few more tips):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("K1:K10")
        Dim Val1 As Variant
        Val1 = cell.Value2
        If Val1 = "Item1" Then
            Dim Val2 As Variant
            Val2 = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value2
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1") = "" Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1") = Val2
            Else
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N33").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Val2
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    Range("N11").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-10]C:R[-1]C)"

End Sub
```

So this line:

```
Val2 = ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Value
```

Changes to:

```
Val2 = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Value
```

Or an every better:

```
Val2 = cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value2
```

Comment: This was also helpful. But I want to do is get rid of the part below. I would like to do the calculations in memory.                                                                                                     `If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1") = "" Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1") = Val2
            Else
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N33").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Val2
            End If`

Comment: @Eric Oh, i get it. Sorry. I mis-read your question. You want to use VBA only and not write the individual values to the worksheet. I'll have the code posted in a minute or two.

Comment: @Eric Answer has been upodated.

Comment: Thanks you so much robinCTS. Also, thanks for the advice/showing me on how to avoid active.

Comment: @Eric You're welcome. Thanks for pointing out the typo - the golden should have read **Never use Activate and ActiveCell** instead of just "Active". I've fixed it in the answer.

Comment: One small issue I found while testing the code is that it does not get anything after the decimal point for example 2.50 becomes just 2. Would I need to change how the variable is declare?

Comment: @Eric Oops. You are absolutely right! `Sum` should have been `Dim`ed as a `Double`, not a `Long`. I've fixed the code in the answer.